# Jquery droppable propagation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

Im trying to make a droppable of elements in a menu. I put 3 divs whit position absolute, in the right-bottom of the page.

See: http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/9927/sinttulo1vv.png

The green div its a div for detect over:

```
   $("#green" ).droppable({
        accept: "div.widget",
        tolerance: 'pointer',


        over: function(event, ui) {
        // show the red div
        }
});
```

The red div its the menu, its display none at first, but when its over of green div this appear.

The blue div its for detect the out:

```
  $("#blue").droppable({
        accept: "div.widget",
        tolerance: 'pointer',

        out: function() {
        // Hide the red div.
        }
});
```

The problem is that when i drop something in th menu, detect first this droppables and never make the drop, make the over and out events but no makes the drop.

Im triing the  greedy option but dont make anything :S

Someone can help me?
Thanks!